# I can't import qs in vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I use vite, ts and vue3. Now I want to use qs.stringfy() to build a url's query, but it panic.

I use `yarn add @types/qs` to add qs.

My code like this

```
    import qs from "qs";
    
    qs.stringify(data)
```

the error is

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "qs" from "src\tools\oauth.ts". Does the file exist?
```

How can I resolve is?

Comment: Did you also install `qs`?

Comment: I finaly write a function to immplate `qs.stringify(data)` as I just want to get an redirect url.

Comment: same problem for me with `svelte` + `vite`.
I installed qs by  `npm install --save @types/qs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe i found the solution. It seems that `@types/qs` contains only type declarations (no sources). Installing both `qs` and `@types/qs` fixed the problem.